# How to handle numerous web forms that vary with the same basic controls?

Tags: webforms, code-behind, ascx, aspx-user-control

I have three `ascx` **web forms user controls** to gather the customer credit card information similar to the following. The **first form web user control** has two basic textbox controls, the second one has four and the last one has one. *For brevity, the other controls are not displayed.*

The **UI designer can create numerous forms by combining the basic controls**. For example, he can *move the first & last name controls to the third form* where the credit card information is gathered.

On every form I have to save some information to the database during the page load as well as when a submit button is clicked. Because there are numerous forms, the code has to be duplicated sometimes in the code behind of the form.

How to solve this problem by reusing the code in the code behind to save information to the database as well as the code can be maintained with SOLID principles?

**First Form:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FirstForm.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.FirstForm" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
... more basic controls
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

**Second Form:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SecondForm.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.SecondForm" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbStreetAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbState" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbZip" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
... more basic controls
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

**Third Form:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Thirdform.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Thirdform" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbCreditCart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
... more basic controls
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

**Code Behind for the first form:**

```
public partial class FirstForm : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    Dim _dbService As DBService

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            _dbService.Save(tbFirstName.Text);
            _dbService.Save(tbLastName.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my first reaction is to use only one control and instead of letting the ui move controls around, show and hide controls, and run code when controls are shown or hidden. second thought is to put all data into a custom class stored in a session variable that is only saved to the db at the end of the entire process.

Comment: One page with all the controls and show/hide logic would be hard to maintain though.